# ngGrid: cannot capture inputs using cellTemplate

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

I am trying to use ngGrid to capture data. I am struggling to get updated `$scope.myData` on submit when inputs are entered on a CellTemplate on the `age` columns.

**Question:**

How do I capture data using cellTemplate and get an updated `$scope.myData` on sumbit?

**Grid A**

[image]

**JS**

```
     $scope.myData = [{name: "Moroni", age: ""},
                   {name: "Tiancum", age: ""},
                   {name: "Jacob", age: ""},
                   {name: "Nephi", age: ""}];

  $scope.gridOptions = { 
    data: 'myData',
    selectedItems: $scope.mySelections,
    multiSelect: true,
    columnDefs: [
      {field: 'name', displayName: 'Name'},
      {field:'age', displayName:'Age', cellTemplate: '<input type="number" placeholder="Enter age" />'}
    ]
  };

  $scope.getUpdatedData = function () {
    console.log($scope.myData);
    $scope.updatedData = $scope.myData;
  };
```

**Grid B**
However this works *without* a cellTemplate

[image]

**JS**

```
// WITHOUT CELL TEMPLATE
  $scope.myData2 = [{name: "Moroni", age: ""},
                   {name: "Tiancum", age: ""},
                   {name: "Jacob", age: ""},
                   {name: "Nephi", age: ""}];

  $scope.gridOptions2 = { 
    data: 'myData2',
    selectedItems: $scope.mySelections,
    enableCellEditOnFocus: true,
    multiSelect: true,
    columnDefs: [
      {field: 'name', displayName: 'Name'},
      {field:'age', displayName:'Age'}
    ]
  };

  $scope.getUpdatedData2 = function () {
    console.log($scope.myData2);
    $scope.updatedData2 = $scope.myData2;
  };
```

**Plnkr:** http://plnkr.co/edit/vey5tGBEcnYJYyUZasg8?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works if you put

```
<input type="number" placeholder="Enter age" ng-input="COL_FIELD" ng-model="COL_FIELD" />
```

as your cellTemplate. I have updated [your plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/EgeIf88jwpDLB3RHaQkX?p=preview) to demonstrate this.